# Results from my program

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I run my code below, I get results for a tie and player two, but player one shows up as NO NAME. Can not figure out why the playerOne variable isnt changed when I type in a name. Novice programmer hoping for help with my work.

```
import random

#the main function
def main():
    print

    #initialize variables
    endProgram = 'no'
    playerOne = 'NO NAME'
    playerTwo = 'NO NAME'

    #call to inputName
    playerOne, playerTwo = inputNames(playerOne, playerTwo)

    #while loop to run program again
    while endProgram == 'no':
        winnerName = 'NO NAME'
        #initialize variables
        p1number = 0
        p2number = 0

        #call to roll dice
        winnerName = rollDice(playerOne, playerTwo, winnerName)

        #call to display info
        winnerName = displayInfo(winnerName)    
        endProgram = raw_input ('Do you want to end the program?  (Enter yes or no): ')

#this function gets the players names
def inputNames(playerOne, playerTwo):
    playerOne = raw_input('Player one enter name ')
    playerTwo = raw_input('Player two enter name ')
    return playerOne, playerTwo

#this function will get the random values
def rollDice(winnerName, playerOne, playerTwo):
    p1number = random.randint (1, 6)
    p2number = random.randint (1, 6)
    if (p1number == p2number):
        winnerName = 'TIE'
    elif (p1number > p2number):
        winnerName = playerOne
    else:
        winnerName = playerTwo
    return winnerName

#this function displays the winner
def displayInfo(winnerName):
    print 'The winners name is ', winnerName

#calls main
main()
```

Comment: Sorry -- StackOverflow isn't a generalized debugging service. Now, if you had narrowed things down to a specific problem or question (ideally with a minimal reproducer -- see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then we'd be in a better place to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the order of arguments in your `rollDice` function.

```
#this function will get the random values
def rollDice(winnerName, playerOne, playerTwo):
    ....
    ....
```

It is expecting `winnerName` as the first argument. In your `main` function you have it set as the last argument.

Change this:

```
winnerName = rollDice(playerOne, playerTwo, winnerName)
```

to this:

```
winnerName = rollDice(winnerName, playerOne, playerTwo)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you can also call function parameters out of order. Then you have to call it with `winnerName = rollDice(playerOne=playerOne, playerTwo=playerTwo, winnerName=winnerName)`

Comment: Thanks for all of you guys' help. Seriously have been staring at this for 2 hours trying to figure it out. My Halloween is made!

Comment: and I don't even know why you have `winnerName` as parameter. You don't use it in the function at all.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the variable playerOne is local to the function "main". When you assign to that variable name in the other functions, you're creating a second, separate value.

If you want to share variables between functions you can use the 'global' keyword to say that, when you update a variable's value, you mean the one in the global variable namespace, not the variable namespace that is local to the function:

```
  def f():
       global x
       x += 1


   x = 99
   print x
   f()
   print x
```

Alternatively, you can return values from functions:

```
def calcNewValue(x):
   return x+1

x = 99
print x
x = calcNewValue(x)
print x
```

Or use classes to hold variable that a common set of function operate on:

```
class GameState:
   def __init__(self):
       self.x = 99
       self.y = "hello"

   def update():
       self.x = self.x +1


s = GameState()
print s.x
s.update()
print s.x
```